# How to use 3rd party libraries and inline scripts in nodejs app while helmet enabled

Tags: content-security-policy, manifest.json, helmet.js

I was developing a nodejs app and implimented some security ,
I used helmet like this

```
app.use(helmet())
```

now browser does not allow me to use third party libraries and inline script . you can check image

So I found solution. see below

```
app.use(helmet({  contentSecurityPolicy: false}))
```

now everything solved .
I want to know that why this happen how to use 3rd party libraries and inline scripts without the setting  contentSecurityPolicy: false in helmet

I also found about we must include a manifest.json file in public folder and mention all third party libraries in it . how to impliment that ? thanks in advance [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helmet maintainer here.

This is happening because of something called Content Security Policy, which Helmet sets by default. To solve your problem, you will need to configure Helmet's CSP.

[MDN has a good documentation about CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) which I would recommend reading for background. After that, take a look at [Helmet's README](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/) to see how to configure its CSP component.

In summary: to solve your problem, you will need to tell Helmet to configure your CSP.